# Getting temporary credentials from EC2/ElasticBeanstalk for API Gateway with IAM authoriser

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, api-gateway

I need to call an API Gateway method protected with IAM authentication from an Elastic Beanstalk application. But to create a signed request, I need access/secret key and session token. So I tried using the MetadataService

```
console.log('Using metadata service');
const metadata = new AWS.MetadataService();
const metadataRequest = util
    .promisify(metadata.request)
    .bind(metadata);
const data = await metadataRequest(
    '/latest/meta-data/identity-credentials/ec2/security-credentials/ec2-instance'
);
sessionData = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(
    'typeof sessionData',
    typeof sessionData,
    sessionData.Token
);
sessionData = {
    ...sessionData,
    SessionToken: sessionData.Token
};
```

but when I called the API I get:

> [9d3a82369277] gfx5000000 Error: Request failed with status code 403
>   at createError
>   (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-api-gateway-client/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
>   at settle
>   (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-api-gateway-client/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:18:12)
>   at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd
>   (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-api-gateway-client/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:202:11)
>   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15) at
>   IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20) at endReadableNT
>   (_stream_readable.js:1129:12) at
>   /var/app/current/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31 at
>   process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

I also tried using `getSessionToken` but realised I cannot do that since I am using a role.

Then I tried assumeRole,

```
console.log('Assuming role');
sessionData = await sts
    .assumeRole({
        RoleArn:
            'arn:aws:iam::906981349885:role/genflix-beanstalk-ec2-role',
        RoleSessionName: 'genflix-eb'
    })
    .promise();
console.log(sessionData);
sessionData = sessionData.Credentials;
```

where I assume the same role as the current EC2, but got:

```
AccessDenied: Access denied
at Request.extractError (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:50:29)
at Request.callListeners (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
at Request.emit (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
at Request.emit (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
at Request.transition (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
at Request.callListeners (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
at Request.emit (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
at Request.emit (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
at Request.transition (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
at Request.callListeners (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
at callNextListener (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:96:12)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:307:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
at /var/app/current/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

What should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Jiew, I would suggest to generate the SDK for API Gateway and use it in your code. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html